# A missing attachment to the QOpenGLFramebufferObject error in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glsl

I`m trying to create a framebuffer with attaching a depth texture to that for rendering dynamic shadows that will be cast from some point light sources. However, after allocating a dynamic memory for QOpenGLFramebufferObject, it throws out an error to me and further refuse to render shadows:

```
QOpenGLFramebufferObject: Framebuffer incomplete, missing attachment.
```

My code:

```
GLvoid GLWindow::initializeGL()
{
    ...

    // The pointer to that object is saved to the GLWindow.
    depthFramebuffer = new QOpenGLFramebufferObject(QSize(4096, 4096), QOpenGLFramebufferObject::Depth, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Looka like a bug in `QOpenGLFramebufferObject`. In GL, when a FBO is created, the default drawbuffer is `GL_COLOR_ATTCHMENT0`. However, when you want a depth-only FBO, you must manually set `glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE)`, otherwise it will point to an non-attached attachment slot, making the FBO incomplete.

Comment: I've added `glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE)` and `glReadBuffer(GL_NONE)` lines after implementing `depthFramebuffer->bind()`, but it continues to output the same error. Also, the shadows don't appear still.